# how to conditionally change commas into semicolon with spark-scala map / split

Tags: regex, scala, amazon-s3, apache-spark

I'm new to spark / scala and have encountered a problem 
I need to have some data manipulations on a full month of data. to achieve this I defined a class

`scala> case class zahiro(request_datetime: String, ip: String, host: String, request_uri: String, referer: String, useragent: String, uuid: String, country: String)`

`scala> val lines = sc.textFile("s3://{bucket}/whatever/2015/05/*.*").map(_.split(",")).map(p
=> zahiro(p(0),p(1),p(2),p(3),p(4),p(5),p(6),p(7))).toDF()`

however, the useragent field may or may not contain "," and is enclosed in double quotes.

what i would like to achieve is conditionally changing the "," with ";" based on the condition that it is enclosed/encapsulated with dbl quotes.

on PIG, I can use : 
xxx = FOREACH xxx GENERATE request_datetime, ip, host, uuid, country, impression_id, impression_datetime,REPLACE(useragent,',',';');

directly after defining the scheme, but I really want to do it on Scala
and not via some pre-processing regex work

any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add fallowing map before splitting

```scala
val lines = sc.textFile("s3://{bucket}/whatever/2015/05/*.*")
  //add the map
  .map(line => line.replaceAll("\",\"", ";"))
  .map(_.split(","))
  .map(p=> zahiro(p(0),p(1),p(2),p(3),p(4),p(5),p(6),p(7)))
```

Comment: Can you give some example?

Comment: what I needed was "\".*,.*\""   - I did not explain myself properly apparently.
anyway - much obliged. after your answer it was just a quick regex check

Answer (score 0):

expanding https://stackoverflow.com/users/3187921/user52045 's comment -

```
val lines = sc.textFile("s3://{bucket}/whatever/2015/05/*.*") 
 //add the map
 .map(line => line.replaceAll("\".*,.*\"", ";"))
 .map(_.split(","))   
 .map(p=> zahiro(p(0),p(1),p(2),p(3),p(4),p(5),p(6),p(7)))
```

works perfectly.